# Placing <div> tags on wordpress visual editor using shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, tinymce, visual-editor

Hello I need to have the following code on a specific page:

```
<div class="searchbar" >

            <div class="searchbar-inner" >

                search <input type="text" id="search" />

                <span class="result-count" ></span>

            </div>

</div>
```

Is it possible that I use a shortcode to place it on the visual editor while editing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have the shortcode written down...

```
function search_shortcode()
{
    $struct = '<div class="searchbar" ><div class="searchbar-inner" >search <input type="text" id="search" /><span class="result-count" ></span></div></div>';
    return $struct;
}
add_shortcode('search_box', 'search_shortcode');
```

Make sure your editor is in the 'HTML' mode, and paste the shortcode as 'search_box'.
Using a shortcode will allow you to reuse this form anywhere you want.

Comment: thanks! just want to ask, why do you need it to be added on the variable $struct? can't it be echo '<div class=....' instead?

Comment: Yes you can, like `return '<div class=...'`! $struct is just a variable to hold the entire mark up string. You can name it anything you like and return it, or even return the markup string directly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use shortcode, but its not necessary.

You can switch to the HTML tab (next to the visual tab) in the post editor and paste your code there.

Also you should format your search input like the one below if you're planning to adhere the WordPress search rules.

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <div class="searchbar-inner">
        <form action="http://example-site-name.tld/" method="get">
            <label for="search">Search</label><input id="search" type="text" name="s" />
        </form>
        <span class="result-count"> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers,